# In jQuery, how do I reference the initial selector when clicked even though it has the same class as other a tags?

Tags: jquery, class, this, href

txtI am using jQuery to do the following:

- Select an a tag and attach the click function to it.
- In the function:
- Prevent default behaviour
- Fetch the clicked elements href attribute and split it after 'html' to leave the ID.
- Animate the body to the ID's offset.

Here is my code:

```
$('.jumpto').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linktxt = $(this).attr('href');
    var link = $(linktxt).split('html')[1];

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
    }, 200);
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<li><a href="your-stay.html#hot-tub" class="jumpto">Hot Tub Hire</a></li>
<li><a href="your-stay.html#dining" class="jumpto">Restaurants and Pubs</a></li>
<li><a href="your-stay.html#peak-district" class="jumpto">The Peak District</a></li>
<li><a href="your-stay.html#things-to-do" class="jumpto">Local Attractions</a></li>
```

I've tried a few variations but can't work out how to reference the a tag with the class of 'jumpto' that has been clicked?

Comment: *Update* I made the mistake of adding the jQuery '$' selector when using the variable 'linktxt' on the 4th line.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using an arrow function, therefore `this` will still refer to the outer scope where the handler is defined instead of the element that was clicked.

You have two options. Firstly, you can keep the arrow functions and use `e.target` to refer to the clicked element instead of `this:`

```
$('.jumpto').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var linktxt = $(e.target).attr('href');
  var link = $(link).split('html')[1];

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
  }, 200);
});
```

Alternatively you can remove the arrow functions and revert back to using anonymous function references:

```
$('.jumpto').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var linktxt = $(this).attr('href');
  var link = $(link).split('html')[1];

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
  }, 200);
});
```

Finally note that you can simplify your code by just putting the fragment in the `href` attribute, like this:

```
<a href="#things-to-do" class="jumpto">Local Attractions</a>
```

Then you can just use that attribute value directly in the JS:

```
$('.jumpto').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 200);
});
```